# enable button according to the value of a field

Tags: javascript, php

I want to enable button if  the value of the checked checkbox is grater than 10.
T try this code but it doesn't work.

```
echo '<table><form>';
$req=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM achat');
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($req)){
echo'<tr>
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="quantité" value="'.$res['quantité'].'"        onClick="act_desact();" >
    </td>  
    </tr>';
    }
<input type="submit" name="submit" disabled="disabled"/>'; 
echo ' </form></table>' ;
```

js:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function act_desact() 
 { 
 if ( document.formulaire.quantité.value >=10 ) 
 document.formulaire.submit.disabled=true; 
 else 
 document.formulaire.submit.disabled=false; 
 }
```

Comment: 10 checkbox ? or checkbox value=10 ? your question is little bit confusion

Comment: multiple(!) issues with the format of your javascript!

Comment: @jothi checkbox value=10

Comment: you have multiple checkbox na so that if all the checkbox value is greater than 10 then only show enable the checkbox is it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementByName()` or `document.getElementById()`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function act_desact() 
 { 
 if ( document.getElementByName("quantité").value >=10 ) 
   document.getElementByName("submit").disabled=true; 
 else 
   document.getElementByName("submit").disabled=false; 
 } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats this `document.formulaire`? Javascript can not speak french.

Use: `document.forms[0]`

So:

```
if ( document.forms[0].quantité.value >=10 ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

count the number of checkbox checked by using **length**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function act_desact() 
{ 
   //length  to count the number of checkbox checked 

 if ( document.getElementByName("quantité").value.length >=10 ) 
  {

       document.getElementByName("submit")[0].disabled=true; 

  }
 else
 {
   document.getElementByName("submit")[0].disabled=false; 

    //use [0] in button 
 } 
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: thanks but I don't want to know the number of checkbox cheked , I want to compare the value of the checked checkbox to 10